# ng-init called before API response

Tags: angularjs

I have function like this in controller

```
this.getStates = function () {
                LoadingService.enableLoading();
                CartService.getStates(self.customerDetails.Country).then(function (response) {
                    response = response.data;
                    self.states = response.State;
                    LoadingService.disableLoading();
                }).catch(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    LoadingService.disableLoading();
                });
            };
```

and in my view it renders in this way

here is the template code

```
<select required id='country' class="form-control" ng-model="checkoutCntrl.customerDetails.Country" ng-init="checkoutCntrl.customerDetails.Country = checkoutCntrl.countries[107]"
                ng-options="item.CountryCode as item.CountryName for item in checkoutCntrl.countries track by item.CountryCode"
                ng-select="checkoutCntrl.getStates()" ng-change="checkoutCntrl.getStates()">
        </select>
```

I wanted to select the default country as how do I select it. when I use function inside ng-init is called before we get the data from the server

here is the next code after setting the country value trying to fetch states

```
this.getStates = function () {
                console.log('obj=====>');
                console.log(self.customerDetails.Country.CountryCode);
                LoadingService.enableLoading();
                CartService.getStates(self.customerDetails.Country).then(function (response) {
                    response = response.data;
                    self.states = response.State;
                    LoadingService.disableLoading();
                }).catch(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    LoadingService.disableLoading();
                });
            };
```

where self.customerDetails.Country is coming as a object

Comment: Please help to show your template code.

Answer (score 0):

ng-init evaluates the expression only once. In your case, since your request is async, by the time your request is successful ng-init is already evaluated. A better way to initialize your variable would be to write this in your success callback

```
checkoutCntrl.customerDetails.Country = checkoutCntrl.countries[107];
```

And if you don't want your select to be displayed before the request, consider using ng-if to render the directive only when your condition is met. For example

```
<div ng-if="showMeOnSuccessfulRequest" >Content...</div>

CartService.getStates(self.customerDetails.Country).then(function (response) {
                response = response.data;
                self.states = response.State;
                $scope.showMeOnSuccessfulRequest = true;
                LoadingService.disableLoading();
            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                LoadingService.disableLoading();
            });
```

Comment: if I do like this it is setting the value but when I trying to get in it is coming as as object instead of value. if I select something else then it is just sending the value instead of object

Comment: and there is another problem that if you select another option after selecting from the controller it will select empty option

Comment: could you brief the scenario you are working, so that i could provide the right example,which will help you understand it better.

Comment: for me select data is coming from the server and default value to be selected as INDIA. and need to call another API for getting the states of INDIA. Right now INDIA is getting selected by your solution then after changing select manually whatever I select blank is getting selected